# struggling with class, extends and implements

Tags: java, android, oop

I'm really struggling with classes, extend and implement.

Well at android I want to create a preference screen and check the user input.

I can use therefore a file named preferences.class and do everything I need with the following class:

```
        public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

        @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
}

      @Override
      public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sp, String key) {
    }
}
```

But isn't it better to split this up in different classes? and if yes how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a `PreferenceChangeListener` which implements `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` and your Preference class will have a `PrefernceChangeListener`

```
public class Preference extends PreferenceActivity {

   private PrefernceChangeListener prefernceChangeListener;

   public void addPreferenceChangeListener(PrefernceChangeListener prefernceChangeListener){
     this.prefernceChangeListener = prefernceChangeListener;
   }

   public PrefernceChangeListener getPrefernceChangeListener(){
     return this.prefernceChangeListener;
   }    
}
```

On a general note if your class has a property which can be externalized you should try to use **HAS A** relationship, you will use **IS A** relationship when your class provides functionality on top of inherited values.

Most of the cases **IS A** can be avoided, unless your class doesnt has a meaning without inheritance favor **HAS A** over **IS A** relationship.

[Prefer composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: Thank you...very helpfull!! I also find different examples at http://tseng-blog.nge-web.net/blog/2009/02/14/implementing-listeners-in-your-android-java-application/